# Update jenkins during long running jobs

Tags: jenkins

I want to upgrade my jenkins master without aborting or waiting for long running jobs to finish on slaves. Is there a plugin available that provides this feature?

We have several build jobs running regression and integration tests which take hours to run. Often, at least one of those jobs is running, making it hard to restart jenkins after updates. I know, that it is poosible to block the queue. We tried this, but it hinders more than it helps.

What we are looking for is a plugin, that runs jobs on slaves, caches the output as soon as the connection to the master is interrupted and sends the remaining output to the master when the master is up again. Does anybody know a plugin providing this feature.